# Mi programa tarda demasiado en conectar a la base de datos

Tags: java, mysql, wamp

Tengo un programa que funciona con una base de datos, lo único es que al probar la conexión (por primera vez) se demora en conectar de 2 a 3 minutos; estoy probando la conexión desde un `JFrame` y un `Button`. Luego de que conecta puedo seguir pulsando el botón y ya no tarda en conectar.

Este es el código de mi conexión, en el `JFrame` únicamente mando llamar a la clase.

```
package bd;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class conexion {

    //variables asignadas para la conexión
    public Connection con;

    public void conexion(){
        con = null;
        try{
            System.out.println("llego a la conexion");
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("2");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dtbase", "root", "");
            System.out.println("3");
                System.out.println("Conexion exitosa");

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection(){
        return con;
    }

}
```

A partir del numero "2" es cuando demora en conectar.

Estoy usando NetBeans y Wampserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando un usuario se conecta, MySQL además de comprobar el nombre de usuario y la contraseña también comprueba el host, osea, resuelve a través del servicio DNS (ya sea local o remoto) la IP y/o dominio desde donde se realiza la conexión. 
Es aquí donde se produce el problema: si el servicio DNS no responde con la rapidez necesaria (algo muy común) se retrasa el login y todo lo demás (consulta, ejecución o lo que sea que se quiera hacer en el servidor).

Al parecer esa es tu situación ya que comentabas que a partir de :

- con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dtbase", "root", "");
  tu programara demoraba.

La solución consiste en agregar "skip-name-resolve" al archivo de configuración de MySQL (my.ini o my.cnf,) y reinicie el servidor MySQL.

Espero ayude.

Comment: Otra cosa que puede funcionar es reemplazar "localhost" por a ip para no realizar ese tipo de conversiones. La línea final quedaría `con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/dtbase", "root", "");`. Espero que ayude :D

Comment: La línea "skip-name-resolve" en que parte del archivo "my.ini" se coloca?

Comment: Puedes colocarlo en la parte donde va:# commented in by lampp security
skip-name-resolve
#skip-networking
#skip-federated